# Android Socket Connects to IP address that has nothing on it

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am having some problems with Sockets on Android. I have an app to which I am adding sockets, so the first thing I did was implement the sockets in a demo application. What it does is it loops through 255 IP addresses in the range 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.0.255 when it successfully connects the server writes data to the output stream and and the client reads the data and displays it to the user, this allows me to scan the wifi network for servers and list them to the user to allow the user to connect to one of them.

As soon as I run the exact same code within the existing application it starts doing strange things. The main issue at the moment is it is successfully connecting to every IP address in the loop.

Attached is a screenshot showing the incorrect behavior I am experiencing. I am expecting an exception being thrown when it tries to connect to an IP address with nothing to connect to.

[image]

The server in the example is running on IP 192.168.0.139 on port 6111 so I am expecting that all other IP's should throw the exception.

It does work as expected in my sample project I created to test this. So the first thing I did was make sure that the code is identical and then that all the gradle file config settings are the same, so I can confirm that they are using the same build tools and targetSdk version.

What else can I check to figure out why in the demo project it works but in the actual app it does not?

Comment: What is 'client'? And if it does not go in an exception then what happens instead?

Comment: So you have two apps with this same code and only one app behaves ok?

Comment: 'IP address that has nothing on it'. You probably mean the following: first: the ip address is not assigned to a device so does not exist. Second: there is a device/pc with that ip but there is no server listening on the specified port.

Comment: @greenapps that is a correct assumption, i can't remember if I ever solved this issue